# Java Code w/ Two Classes

Tags: java, class

I am stuck on the second class of the below code. Can you take a look? I am receiving the error message, "illegal start of type" for my "while(true)" loop. I'm not looking for an entirely different way to do the code, more of a solution to the problem I'm having.

Here's the problem that was given:

Write a Java program the displays the State bird and flower. You should use your IDE for this exercise. You should also use Java classes to their full extent to include multiple methods and at least two classes. The program should prompt the user to enter a State and print both the State bird and flower. The user should be able to enter a State without worrying about case. (e.g. Users could enter Maryland, maryland, MARYLAND or any other possible combination of lower and upper case characters. States may also contain leading and trailing white spaces. Hint: Store the State information in a multidimensional array. The program should continue to prompt the user to enter a state until “None” is entered. You will need to do some research to find the State birds and flowers.

```
public class State4 {

   private String state [][] = {
        {"ALABAMA","Nothern Flicker","Camellia"},
        {"ALASKA","Willow Ptarmigan","Forget-me-not"},
        {"ARIZONA","Cactus Wren","Saguaro Cactus Blossom"},
        {"ARKANSAS","Mockingbird","Apple Blossom"},
        {"CALIFORNIA","California Quail","California Poppy"},
        {"COLORADO","Lark Bunting","Rocky Mountain Columbine"}, 
        {"CONNECTICUT","American Robin","Mountain Laurel"},
        {"DELAWARE","Blue Hen","Peach Blossom"},
        {"FLORIDA","Northern Mockingbird","Orange Blossom"},
        {"GEORGIA","Brown Thrasher","Azalea"},
        {"HAWAII","Hawaiian Goose","Hawaiian Hibiscus"},
        {"IDAHO","Mountain Bluebird","Mock Oragnge"},
        {"ILLINOIS","Northern Cardinal","Violet"},
        {"INDIANA","Cardinal","Peony"},
        {"IOWA","Eastern Goldfinch","Iowa"},
        {"KANSAS","Western Meadowlark","Sunflower"},
        {"KENTUCKY","Northern Cardinal","Goldenrod"},
        {"LOUISIANA","Brown Pelican","Magnolia"},
        {"MAINE","Black-capped Chickadee","White Pine Cone and Tassel"},
        {"MARYLAND","Baltimore Oriole","Black-eyed Susan"},
        {"MASSACHUSETTS","Black-capped Chickadee","Mayflower"},
        {"MICHIGAN","American Robin","Apple Blossom"},
        {"MISSISSIPPI","Northern Mockingbird","Magnolia"},
        {"MISSOURI","Eastern Bluebird","Hawthorn (flower)"},
        {"MONTANA","Western Meadowlark","Bitterroot"},
        {"NEBRASKA","Western Meadowlark","Goldenrod"},
        {"NEVADA","Mountain Bluebird","Sagebrush"},
        {"NEW HAMPSHIRE","Purple Finch","Purple Lilac"},
        {"NEW JERSEY","Eastern Goldfinch","Violet"},
        {"NEW MEXICO","Roadruner","Yucca Flower"},
        {"NEW YORK","Eastern Bluebird","Rose"},
        {"NORTH CAROLINA","Northern Cardinal","Flowering Dogwood"},
        {"NORTH DAKOTA","Western Meadowlark","Wild Prairie Rose"},
        {"OHIO","Northern Cardinal","Scarlet Carnation"},
        {"OKLAHOMA","Scissor-tailed Flycatcher","Oklahoma Rose"},
        {"OREGON","Western Meadowlark","Oregon Grape"},
        {"RHODE ISLAND","Rhode Island Red","Violet"},
        {"SOUTH CAROLINA","Carolina Wren","Yellow Jessamine"},
        {"SOUTH DAKOTA","Ring-necked Pheasant","Pasque Flower"},
        {"TENNESSEE","Nothern Mockingbird","Iris"},
        {"TEXAS","Northern Mockingbird","Bluebonnet"},
        {"UTAH","California Gull","Sego Lily"},
        {"VERMONT","Hermit Thrush","Red Clover"},
        {"VIRGINIA","Northern Cardinal","American Dogwood"},
        {"WASHINGTON","Willow Goldfinch","Coast Rhodedendron"},
        {"WEST VIRGINIA","Northern Cardinal","Rhodedendrom"},
        {"WISCONSIN","American Robin","Wood Violet"},
        {"WYONMING","Western Meadolark","Indian Paintbrush"},
    };

   public State4(){

   }
   public String[][] getState() {
       return state;
   }
   public void setState(String[][] state) {
       this.state = state;
   }


}
```

//Here's the second class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestState4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    int position = -1;
    boolean found = false;

    //Negating Case Sensitivity
    //same length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case
    for(int i=0;i<state4.length && !found;i++){
        if(states4[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(state))
            position=i;
        }
    return position;
    }   

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    state4 inform = new state4();
    String states[][] =inform.getState();

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter a State or 'None' to exit:");
        String state = input.next();

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("None")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    else{
        int position = getInfo(stateData, stateName);
        if(position != -1){
            System.out.println("Bird: " + stateData[position][1]);
            System.out.println("Flower: " + stateData[position][2] + "\n\n");
        }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please try again, an invalid State was entered.");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the balance of opening and closing curly braces in the `main` function.

Comment: I think it should be `State4` instead of `state4`. Java is case sensitive. Eg: `State4 inform = new State4();`

Comment: Also, in your first `for` loop, you're using some variables `state4` and `states4` which don't seem to be declared anywhere in that class.

Answer (score 0):

for your question, probably here

```
for(int i=0;i<state4.length && !found;i++) {
    if(states4[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(state))
        position=i;
    }

    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it use input.next() , you should input.nextLine() because some of the state contain 2 words, below is the solution based on your request, hope this can help

```
public class TestState4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    State4 inform = new State4();
    String states[][] = inform.getState();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a State or 'None' to exit:");

        String state = input.nextLine();

        if (state.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("None")) {
            break;
        } else {
            int index = getStateIndex(state, states);
            if (index != -1) {
                System.out.printf("Bird: %s \nFlower: %s \n",
                        getBird(index, states), getFlower(index, states));
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("Please try again, an invalid State was entered.");
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
}

private static int getStateIndex(String state, String[][] states) {
    for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        if (state.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(states[i][0])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private static String getBird(int index, String[][] states) {
    return states[index][1];
}

private static String getFlower(int index, String[][] states) {
    return states[index][2];
}}
```